# Is 'this' a mutable state in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

One can think of **this** as implicit variable set on runtime. If it can be set to different values it may affect behavior of a function and value it returns, making the function impure. In below example objOne.addTwo function calls only another pure function, but because of **this** it can be changed.

#### Example

```js
const objOne = {
  getTwo: () => 2,
  addTwo: function (num) {
    return num + this.getTwo();
  }
}
const objTwo = {
  getTwo: () => 3
}
console.log(objOne.addTwo(2)); // Returns 4
console.log(objOne.addTwo.call(objTwo, 2)); // Returns 5 instead of 4
```

#### Question

As a principle, should **this** be considered "mutable state"?

Comment: Btw, different expressions (method invocations here) may evaluate to different values, hence your example is pure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `this` keyword by itself isn't considered mutable state. Consider the following program.

```js
const objOne = {
  getTwo: () => 2,
  addTwo: function (self, num) {
    return num + self.getTwo();
  }
}

const objTwo = {
  getTwo: () => 3
}

console.log(objOne.addTwo(objOne, 2)); // Returns 4
console.log(objOne.addTwo(objTwo, 2)); // Returns 5 instead of 4
```

The above program clearly has no mutation. It's exactly the same as your original program except that it uses a formal parameter instead of using the `this` keyword.

---

However, `this` is usually used together with mutation in OOP. For example, consider the following class.

```js
class Vec2 {
    constructor(x, y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    add(that) {
        this.x += that.x;
        this.y += that.y;
    }
}

const v1 = new Vec2(1, 2);
const v2 = new Vec2(3, 4);

v1.add(v2);

console.log(v1); // { x: 4, y: 6 }
```

Clearly, you can have mutation without using `this` too.

```js
const Vec2 = (x, y) => ({ x, y });

const add = (self, that) => {
    self.x += that.x;
    self.y += that.y;
};

const v1 = Vec2(1, 2);
const v2 = Vec2(3, 4);

add(v1, v2);

console.log(v1); // { x: 4, y: 6 }
```

So, `this` is just a special parameter of sorts. By itself, it isn't mutable. However, you can mutate it just as you can mutate any other parameter.

---

The bigger problem with the `this` keyword, and the `new` keyword too, are that they are special cases. Normally, you'd call a function as `foo(x, y, z)`, but with `this` you'd have to call the function as `foo.call(x, y, z)`, and with `new` you'd have to call the function as `new foo(x, y, z)`.

These special cases make it difficult to reuse higher order functions. For example, normally you can do `[1, 2, 3].map(foo)` but what if the call to `foo` needs to be prefixed with `new`? Then, you'd have to write `[1, 2, 3].map((...args) => new foo(...args))`. Similarly, what if `foo` needs to be called using `.call`? Then, you'd have to write `[1, 2, 3].map((...args) => foo.call(...args))`.

Clearly, these special cases are making life more complicated, at least in the case of functional programming. To quote the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

> Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.

**TLDR:** Avoid using `this` and `new` when writing programs in a functional style.

Answer (score 2):

It's rather a philosophical question IMO. I think it depends on what you understand by *mutable state*. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) we read:

> It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

This clearly explains that `this` cannot be set during function execution but it may be different depending on how you call the function. So if we are talking about reassigning `this` then no, it's not a mutable state because it's not possible to change its value after it's been set. But we can change it by calling a function differently.

You can read about those ways of changing `this` by calling a function differently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Answer (score -1):

From my Perspective I don't say **this** is mutable state.

And what happened is something related to Javascript **Lexical scope** and **ScopeManager**

When **ScopeManager** finds **this** in your function , **ScopeManager** starts searching in his **Lexical Scope** about the closest **this** value unless you are using **Hard Binding** as you did when you use `call`

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with *scope* per se. It's unclear whether what you've written is wrong or just misleading.

Comment: Imagine it when you write `this` in your function the Scope Manager will search for variable with name `this` and If It couldn't find any variable with `this` name Scope Manager will search for the nearest outer scope ... example when you write this in normal function the value will be the `window` value and that is not in strict mode.

Comment: And you can force `this` value by using `Hard Binding` using `call`,`bind` and `apply`

Comment: `this` isn't a normal variable and doesn't work that way. Each function has its own `this`. You'll never get a parent scope's `this`. (You can argue about that with fat arrow functions perhaps, but that's an implementation detail.)

Comment: I didn't say `this` is normal variable I said imagine it as normal variable and what is your explanation when you write `this` inside normal function not constructor function why `this` in this case will return the `window` value ?

Comment: *"why `this` in this case will return the `window` value"* — Because of the rules how `this` is bound at calltime. If it was regular *scope* resolution, and you'd have nested functions, then instead of `window` you'd expect the *parent scope's `this`* to be used instead, which is not the case.

Comment: Because in this case also the parent function doesn't have `this` so it will search in the outer scope until it goes to global scope

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205754/discussion-between-ahmed-kesha-and-deceze).